# SQL, finding text with two identifiers

Tags: sql, select

I have some rows in my table that I need to delete.

The rows that must be delete all have strings with two `"***"` in them, for example `"This is a ***example of *** a bad row"`.

How can I `SELECT` these rows, so I can check them out and delete them afterwards?

I know I can use `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%***%'` but that also selects the rows with just one `"***"` in them (the rows that must be deleted have two `"***"` in them).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE column LIKE '%***%***%'
```

This will, however, also delete any rows where there are three or more `"***"`. If you don't want that, you can do

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE column LIKE '%***%***%'
  AND column NOT LIKE '%***%***%***%'
```